# SQLite set check constrain DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to set a check constrain DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED in SQLite, in the following way:

```
CONSTRAINT CheckReference CHECK (ReferenceID IN (SELECT ReferenceID FROM HasReference))
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

But this gives an error. How do i set a CHECK constrain DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [CREATE TABLE syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), only foreign key constraints can be deferred.